# question about the dimension of the global section space of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Suppose that $L,L^{'}$ are a line bundle over a compact riemann surface $C$. Take $H^0(C,L\otimes L^{'})$.
Is it true that $h^0(C,L\otimes L^{'})=h^0(C,L)+h^0(C,L^{'})$ where $h^0(V)$ ,means the complex dimension?

Comment: No. Have you tried some examples?

Comment: @Alex Youcis is the statement  negative even if i suppose that both of lines bundle satisfy the relation that the double tensor product is equivalent to the caninical bundle?

Answer (score 3):

This is false: let $C = \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ and let $L = \mathcal{O}(-1)$ and $L' = \mathcal{O}(1)$. Then,
$$2 = \underbrace{h^0(C,L)}_{=0} + \underbrace{h^0(C,L')}_{=2} \neq h^0(C, L \otimes L') = 1.$$

It might be more reasonable to expect the dimensions to multiply i.e. have 
$$
h^0(C,L) \cdot h^0(C,L') = h^0(C,L\otimes L'),
$$
because there is a natural map $H^0(C,L) \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} H^0(C,L') \to H^0(C,L \otimes L')$. However, this will not always be true, since this map is not an isomorphism, in general. (If $C$ is an affine scheme over $\mathbb{C}$, then this will be true: see the excellent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307392/conditions-such-that-taking-global-sections-of-line-bundles-commutes-with-tensor) by Georges Elencwajg.)

Comment: I think you made a mistake. $h^0(C,L\otimes L')=0$. Maybe $L=\mathcal{O}(-1)$ and $L'=\mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: Good catch, thanks!