# Do we have $(\mathcal L\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal L)(X)=\mathcal L(X)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X(X)}\mathcal L(X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal L$ an invertible sheaf on $X$, do we have $(\mathcal L\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal L)(X)=\mathcal L(X)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X(X)}\mathcal L(X)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Let $X = \Bbb P^1_k$ and $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}(1)$. Then $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes 2} = \mathcal{O}(2)$, and the $\dim_k\mathcal{O}(2)(X)=3$. On the other hand, $\dim_k \mathcal{O}(1)(X) = 2$, so $\dim_k \mathcal{O}(1)(X)\otimes_k \mathcal{O}(1)(X) = 4$, so these vector spaces cannot be isomorphic, let alone equal.

On the other hand, there is always a canonical map $\mathcal{F}(U)\otimes \mathcal{G}(U)\to (\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})(U)$ for any sheaves $\mathcal{F,G}$ and any open $U$. Not much is known about about how nice this map has to be in general, see Martin Brandenburg's answer at [Conditions such that taking global sections of line bundles commutes with tensor product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307392/conditions-such-that-taking-global-sections-of-line-bundles-commutes-with-tensor) for some additional details.