# Sections of tensor bundle are tensor product of sections

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles

Given $E,F$ vector bundles over a manifold $M$, I would like to know a proof of
$\Gamma(E\otimes F) = \Gamma(E) \otimes_{C^\infty(M)} \Gamma(F)$. Where $\Gamma$ denotes the smooth sections over $M$. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The statement is trivially true if $E$ is a trivial vector bundle. Note also that if the statement is true for $E$, then it is also true for any direct summand of $E$. The conclusion follows from the fact that any vector bundle on a manifold is a subbundle of a trivial vector bundle.

Comment: you are using a deep fact to prove a trivial result!

Comment: Well, "deep" is of course a relative notion. The fact that any vector bundle on a manifold is a direct summand of a trivial vector bundle does not seem so deep to me. It is quite easily proved using partitions of unity. Exactly the same technique can be used to show OP's statement. I thought it was kind of economical to use the former fact in order to prove the latter...

Comment: That is true, but these modules are canonically isomorphic, and I don't quite see how your argument gives a canonical isomorphism (which I think the op desires, for he writes "=" instead of just isomorphic). A nice exposition (containing these canonical isomorphism) is "connections, curvature, and cohomology I"

Comment: There is a canonical morphism, but it just needs to be checked that it is an isomorphism. This approach does work, as shown in the [answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492166/global-sections-of-a-tensor-product-of-vector-bundles-on-a-smooth-manifold) (of which this is a duplicate).

Comment: BTW if the base space is not compact then a vector bundle is not necessarilly a summand of a trivial bundle. For example the tautological line bundle on \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$. But I think that the result in the OP question is true for non compact base space.