# Tensors are $C^\infty(M)$-multilinear maps

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, vector-bundles

Here we deal with finite-rank real vector bundles over the same base $M$. I focus on order 2 tensor in order to keep the notation simple.

In most DG texts it is proved that

> **Result 1.** Tensors are $C^\infty(M)$-multilinear maps.

More precisely the 
space of (let's say) $(2,0)$ tensors $\mathcal{T}^{2,0}(M) =
\Gamma(T^*M \otimes T^*M)$ is isomorphic, as $C^\infty(M)$-module,
with the module of $C^\infty(M)$-bilinear forms $\Gamma(TM) \times
\Gamma(TM) \to C^{\infty}(M)$.

The proof consist of showing that a $C^\infty(M)$-multilinear map can be localized and indeed acts pointwise. The other direction is easy.

Then we have

> **Result 2.** Given two vector bundles $E_1,E_2$ over $M$, we have:
>   $$ \mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma(E_1),\Gamma(E_2)) \cong \Gamma(\mathrm{Hom(E_1,E_2)})$$
>   as $C^\infty(M)$-modules. Where $\mathrm{Hom}(E_1,E_2)$ is the homomorphism bundle.

The proof of this result is essentially the same of result 1, carried out for general vector bundles (even thought in the linear and not multi-linear context)

**So I was wondering if I could deduce the first one from the latter.**

**But**, in order to proceed we need the following [non-trivial result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492166/global-sections-of-a-tensor-product-of-vector-bundles-on-a-smooth-manifold)

> **Result 3**
>   $$\Gamma(E_1 \otimes_\mathbb{R} E_2) \cong \Gamma(E_1) \otimes_{C^{\infty}(M)} \Gamma(E_2)$$
>   as $C^\infty(M)$-modules

Now we can exchange $\Gamma$ with $\otimes$:

$$\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma(TM) \otimes \Gamma(TM), C^{\infty}(M)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma(TM \otimes TM), C^{\infty}(M))$$
by result 3.

*Then* we can apply result 2 obtaining:
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma(TM \otimes TM), C^{\infty}(M)) \cong \Gamma(\mathrm{Hom}(TM \otimes TM, M \times \mathbb{R})) \cong \Gamma(T^*M \otimes T^*M)$$
using properties of $\mathrm{Hom}, \otimes$ and $\cdot^*$.

---

**The problem**

In proving result 1 from result 2, I used result 3 to exchange $\Gamma$ and $\otimes$. In the meantime I found this approach (proving 1 using 2 and 3) also in [Conlon's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-8176-4767-4) (Chapter 7).

Considered that proof of 1 and 2 are really much the same and result 3 is not trivial at all:

- Can result 1 be deduced from result 2 without using result 3? In
  other words, **starting from result 2**, do we need the general
  result 3 to prove result 1?
- How, in the usual proof of result 1, we can avoid to pass from result 3?

The fact is that in the proof we use result 3 only to pass from a multilinear setting to a linear one in order to apply result 2

Thanks

Comment: I don't get your reasoning. The usual proof of (1) is totally local, and the applications are always local. I don't see why we need to know anything about global sections to work locally or prove something local.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment. I completely reworked the question. May I ask you to read it again? I hope I clarified a bit