# Covariant derivative of a section along a smooth vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Suppose $E$ is a $q$-dimensional real vector bundle on a smooth manifold $M$ and $\Gamma(E)$ is the set of smooth sections of $E$ on $M$. A connection on the vector bundle $E$ is a map
$$
D:\Gamma(E) \to\Gamma(T^*(M)\otimes E)\tag{1}
$$
which satisfies the following conditions:

- For any $s_1,s_2\in\Gamma(E)$, $D(s_1+s_2)=Ds_1+Ds_2$.
- For $s\in\Gamma(E)$ and any $\alpha\in C^\infty(M)$,
  $$
  D(\alpha s) = d\alpha\otimes s + \alpha Ds\;.
  $$

Suppose $X$ is a smooth tangent vector field on $M$ and $s\in\Gamma(E)$. Let
$$
D_Xs:=\langle X, Ds\rangle\;\tag{2}
$$
where $\langle\;,\rangle$ represents the pairing between $T(M)$ and $T^*(M)$. Then $D_Xs$ is a section of $E$, which is called the covariant derivative of the section $s$ along $X$. This definition is given in Chern's *Lectures on Differential Geometry*.

By (1), $Ds$ is an element in $\Gamma(T^*(M)\otimes E)$, not $\Gamma(T^*(M))$. On the other hand, $X\in\Gamma(T(M))$. How should I understand the pairing in (2)?

---

In John Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds*, a connection in $E$ is a map
$$
\nabla : T(M)\times \Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E)\tag{3}
$$
written $(X,Y)\mapsto \nabla_XY$, satisfying

- $C^\infty(M)$-linear in the first component;
- $\mathbb{R}$-linear in the second component;
- the product rule
  $$
  \nabla_X(fY) = f\nabla_XY+(Xf)Y\;.
  $$

Essentially $\nabla_XY=D_XY$ in Chern's notation; we can show that (2) satisfies all the defining properties for (3).

Are there some reasons we would like to go to the more abstract definition in (1) instead of (3)?

Comment: It's totally the same definition. Finding the covariant derivative of $s$ in the direction of $X$ is evaluating the $1$-form in $Ds$ on $X$. Chern does (did) his mathematics with differential forms — as do many of us — and so this approach was more natural. He wants to think of curvature as a $\text{Hom}(E,E)$-valued $2$-form, not as a repeated covariant derivative operator. But forms are beautiful to compute with.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks. Could you say a bit more on Chern's approach? So instead of considering a linear map, say, $T: V^*\times V\to\mathbb{R}$, it may be more convenient to deal with the linear map $T:V^*\to V^*$? Does this have anything to do with ["currying"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)? Also, to see the equivalency between (1) and (3), we need $\Gamma(T^*M\otimes E)=\Gamma(T^*M)\otimes\Gamma(E)$, right?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645564/is-it-true-that-gamma-lambdatm-cong-lambda-gammatm/3645662#3645662) for your latter question. The real question is this: Do you understand and work with differential forms as differential forms, or do you try to evaluate on vector fields immediately and avoid the forms? :D I don't really see your question with $T$; it's really about whether you .work with $V^*\otimes E$ or with $\text{Hom}(V,E)$. Currying seems to be a computer science issue, but it certainly shows up naturally in analysis and differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The pairing $TM \times (T^* M \otimes E) \to E$ is really just the canonical pairing $\operatorname{tr}: TM \times T^* M \to \Bbb R$ with the tensorial factor $E$ coming along (inertly) for the ride: More precisely, by definition
$$\langle \,\cdot\, , \,\cdot\, \rangle$$
is the composition
$$TM \times (T^* M \otimes E) \stackrel{\otimes}{\longrightarrow} TM \otimes T^* M \otimes E \stackrel{\operatorname{tr} \otimes \operatorname{id}_E}{\longrightarrow} E .$$
On decomposable elements,
$$\langle X, \alpha \otimes \xi \rangle = \alpha(X) \xi .$$

As for comparing the definitions, only a little unwinding is required to show that the two are coincident; I cannot improve on Ted Shifrin's comment about Chern's form approach to geometry.