# Sections of tensor product of vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

According to [Global (smooth) sections of a tensor product of vector bundles on a smooth manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492166/global-sections-of-a-tensor-product-of-vector-bundles-on-a-smooth-manifold), there exists an isomorphism of $C^{\infty}(M)$-modules
$$\Gamma(V,M)\otimes_{C^{\infty}(M)}\Gamma(W,M)\rightarrow\Gamma(V\otimes W,M)$$
for a smooth manifold $M$ and two smooth real vector bundles $V,W$ over $M$. My question is what can we say about the vector space of all continuous sections of the tensor product bundle $V\otimes W$ over $X$
$$\Gamma(V\otimes W,X)$$
when $X$ is an arbitary topological space and $V,W$ are merely real vector bundles?

> Do we have a similar result as above?

Comment: What do you mean by $X$ arbitrary? any topological space? and what how do you take sections of a vector space? do you mean sections of the trivial bundle $X\times(V\otimes W)\to X$? Finally, what kind of results do you expect or need?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Thank you, edited

Comment: What kind of sections? In the smooth manifold case, the result applies to smooth sections. In the case you are asking about, are you considering continuous sections?

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you, edited

Comment: Ok, so there always is a map $\Gamma(V,X)\otimes_{C^0(X)}\Gamma(W,X)\rightarrow\Gamma(V\otimes W,X)$ of $C^0(X)$-modules. If $X$ is compact hausdorff, a partition of unity similar to the one in the smooth case shows this map is an isomorphism. I haven't though about the more general cases.