# Tensor product of invertible sheaf is still invertible sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In general, the tensor product of two sheaves is the sheafication of the tensor product of two presheaves. So how can we see the tensor product of locally free sheaf with rank 1 is locally free with rank 1? Is it true in this case these two notion are actually the same? I am very confused, thanks for any help!

Comment: Related? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/tensor-product-of-invertible-sheaves

Comment: The tensor product is local in that $(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{G})_{|U}=\mathcal{F}_{|U}\otimes_{{\mathcal O}_U}\mathcal{G}_{|U}$. Clearly being a locally free sheaf of rank 1 is also local. So you just need to prove that tensor product of free sheaves of rank 1 is still free of rank 1, in other words that $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_X$ which is obvious.

Comment: @Roland I am sorry, why we have the first identity?

Comment: There are numerous ways to prove it. For instance, you have a natural map $(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})_{|U}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}_{|U}\otimes\mathcal{G}_{|U}$, which is clearly an isomorphism on stalks.